# On Windows 10, grant a user rights to create, edit and delete files in the folder C:\VMs, but prevent deletion of the folder itself

Tags: windows, powershell, virtual-machine

I need users to be able to access and modify contents in a folder C:\VMs. I'm using https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html as a guide. At the bottom of the page there is a list of commands to do exactly what I need, but the first command is not working.

In Powershell I am typing

```
icacls.exe "C:\VMware" /inheritance:r /grant:r testuser:(OI) (CI) (F)
```

and am getting the error

```
The term 'OI' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...
```

I've tried various iterations using different spacing and quotations and the likes but have not had any luck.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [brackets have a special meaning in Powershell](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_brackets.htm).  They must be quoted if they are to be passed as-is to an external program.  The article you link to assumes that you are using the legacy command shell, which does not give brackets a special meaning in this context.

One way to make this work is to use the backtick as an escape character:

```
icacls test /grant Everyone:`(OI`)`(CI`)`(RX`)
```

Since you are running Windows 10, you can use the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about_parsing?view=powershell-5.1) instead:

```
icacls test --% /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)(RX)
```

The stop-parsing symbol requires Powershell 3 or later, so it will not work out-of-the-box on a Windows 7 machine, but on Windows 10 you'll be fine.